# Open MPI and Boost MPI using too many file handles

Tags: sockets, boost, mpi, openmpi, filehandle

I'm running a project using Boost MPI (1.55) over Open MPI (1.6.1) on a compute cluster.

Our cluster has nodes that have 64 CPUs and we spawn a single MPI process on each. Most of our communication is between individual processes, each having a series of irecv() requests open (for different tags) and sends are carried out blocking using send().

The problem we're getting is that after a short time of processing (usually under 10 minutes), we're getting this error that is causing the program to end:

```
[btl_tcp_component.c:1114:mca_btl_tcp_component_accept_handler] accept() failed: Too many open files in system (23).
```

Closer debugging shows that it's network sockets that are taking up these file handles, and we're hitting our OS limit of 65536 file handles open. Most of these are in the status "TIME_WAIT", which is apparently what TCP does for (usually) 60 seconds after a socket is closed (in order to catch any late packets) . I was under the impression that Open MPI didn't close sockets(http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tcp#tcp-socket-closing) and just kept up to N^2 sockets open so that all processes could talk to each other. Obviously 65536 is way beyond 64^2 (the most common cause of this error involving MPI is simply that the file limit is less than N^2) and most of those were sockets that were in a recently closed status.

Our C++ code is too large to fit here, but I've written a simplified version of some of it to at least show our implementation and see if there are any issues with our technique. Is there something in our usage of MPI that would be causing OpenMPI to close and reopen too many sockets?

```
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;
mpi::communicator world;

bool poll(ourDataType data, mpi::request & dataReq, ourDataType2 work, mpi::request workReq) {
  if(dataReq.test()) {
    processData(data); // do a bunch of work
    dataReq = world.irecv(mpi::any_source, DATATAG, data);
    return true;
  }
  if(workReq.test()) {
    int target = assess(work);
    world.send(target, DATATAG, dowork);
    world.irecv(mpi::any_source, WORKTAG, data);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

bool receiveFinish(mpi::request finishReq) {
  if (finishReq.test()) {
    world.send(0, RESULTS, results);
    resetSelf();
    finishReq = world.irecv(0, FINISH);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void run() {
  ourDataType data;
  mpi::request dataReq = world.irecv(mpi::any_source, DATATAG, data);
  ourDataType2 work;
  mpi::request workReq = world.irecv(mpi::any_source, WORKTAG, work);
  mpi::request finishReq = world.irecv(0, FINISH); // the root process can call a halt

  while(!receiveFinish(finishReq)) {
    bool doWeContinue = poll(data, dataReq);
    if(doWeContinue) {
      continue;
    }
    // otherwise we do other work
    results = otherwork();
    world.send(0, RESULTS, results);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh dear C++, so please take the following with the huge caveat that I don't understand that language ... Anyway I can't see any mpi_wait or mpi_test - whenever you have a non-blocking mpi communication there MUST be a corresponding wait. My suspicion is without these sockets aren't being closed, but I must stress that's a guess as the wait/test might be elsewhere, or C++ might be even weirder than I currently think.

Comment: Yeah @IanBush, C++ hasn't been too friendly with us. With the Boost MPI layer on top, the statements like dataReq.test() are analogous to mpi_test on that particular irecv. I'm not sure if there's also a need for a wait if there is regular polling with test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the real reason for Open MPI opening so many sockets, but you appear to be leaking requests in the following part of `poll()` function:

```
if(workReq.test()) {
  int target = assess(work);
  world.send(target, DATATAG, dowork);
  world.irecv(mpi::any_source, WORKTAG, data); // <-------
  return true;
}
```

The request handle as returned by `world.irecv()` is never saved and thus lost. If called periodically on the same `workReq` object, this branch will execute each the time after the completion of the request since testing an already completed request always returns `true`. Therefore you will start lots of non-blocking receives that will never be waited on or tested. Not to mention the messages sent.

Similar problem exists in `receiveFinish` - `finishReq` is being passed by value and the assignment won't affect the value in `run()`.

A side note: is this really the code you use? It appears that the `poll()` function you call in `run()` takes two arguments while the one show here takes four arguments and there are no arguments with default values.

Comment: Hi Hristo and thanks for your input. This isn't the code we run, it's basically a paraphrased version of it because it's quite large and complicated. The irecv line you pointed out was a mistake and should have read: `workReq = world.irecv(mpi::any_source, WORKTAG, data);` However I had a look at our code and we are indeed passing some of the requests by value (while in other places by reference). That could indeed be the source of the problem

Comment: It looks like the requests being passed by value instead of reference was my problem. Thanks a bunch for spotting it.